# Neo4 giving error:" Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Unable to retrieve server info [500]:"

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

```
require('phar://neo4jphp.phar');  
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client();
if($client)
{  
    echo 'Connected';
}
```

i am  using neo4j version 1.9  RC1,
i am able to access  server via  myip:7474,
Curl is Enabled.

Error is :

```
couldn't connect Host[7]
```

Please Help

Comment: Can you add more information? Like a stack trace? Were you able to get to the web admin console?

Comment: Also, creating a client doesn't actually mean you are "connected." No communication happens with the server until you actually try to save a change. Can you provide more code around where the error is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create the client, you must specify the transport you want to use, if you want to use Curl:

```
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client(new Everyman\Neo4j\Transport\Curl('localhost', 7474));
```

or with Stream:

```
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client(new Everyman\Neo4j\Transport\Stream('localhost', 7474));
```