# neo4jphp exception :Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Unable to retrieve server info [500]'

Tags: php, neo4j, xampp, neo4jphp

I am trying to connect neo4j to php.I am working on windows and using XAMPP server.

I found  a similar question as mine.
[Neo4 giving error:" Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Unable to retrieve server info [500]:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386164/neo4-giving-error-uncaught-exception-everyman-neo4j-exception-with-message) .

As per the solution given in the above link.I get the following error.

```
       Fatal error: Undefined constant 'Everyman\Neo4j\Transport\Curl' in C:\xampp\htdocs\con1.php on line 4
```

I tried running php neo4jphp.phar thrugh command line,I get the following error

```
            Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Unable to retrieve server info [500]:
            Headers: Array
            (
            )
            Body: Array
            (
                [error] => Could not resolve host: 7474 [6]
            )
            ' in phar://C:/xampp/php/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command.php:116
            Stack trace:
            #0 phar://C:/xampp/php/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command/GetServerInfo.php(52): Everyman\Neo4j\Command->throwExce
            ption('Unable to retri...', 500, Array, Array)
            #1 phar://C:/xampp/php/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command.php(69): Everyman\Neo4j\Command\GetServerInfo->handleRes
            ult(500, Array, Array)
            #2 phar://C:/xampp/php/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Client.php(587): Everyman\Neo4j\Command->execute()
            #3 phar://C:/xampp/php/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Client.php(360): Everyman\Neo4j\Client->runCommand(Object(Everym
            an\Neo4j\Command\GetServerInfo))
            #4 C:\xampp\php\neo4jphp.phar(45): Everyman\Neo4j\Client->getServerInfo()
            #5 {main}
              thrown in phar://C:/xampp/php/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command.php on line 116
```

Also ,when I run the following code

```
<?php
      use Everyman\Neo4j\Client,
          Everyman\Neo4j\Transport;
      require('neo4jphp.phar');
          $client = new Client(new Transport('localhost', 7474)); 
          print_r($client->getServerInfo());
          ?>
```

I get the following error

```
                Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Unable to retrieve server info [500]: 
            Headers: Array ( ) Body: Array ( [error] => Failed connect to localhost:7474; No error [7] ) 
            ' in phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command.php:116 Stack trace: 
            #0 phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command/GetServerInfo.php(52): Everyman\Neo4j\Command->throwException('Unable to retri...', 500, Array, Array) 
            #1 phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command.php(69): Everyman\Neo4j\Command\GetServerInfo->handleResult(500, Array, Array) 
            #2 phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Client.php(587): Everyman\Neo4j\Command->execute() 
            #3 phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Client.php(360): Everyman\Neo4j\Client->runCommand(Object(Everyman\Neo4j\Command\GetServerInfo)) 
            #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\con1.php(9): Everyman\Neo4j\Client->getServerInfo() 
            #5 {main} thrown in phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/neo4jphp.phar/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command.php on line 116
```

What could possibly be the error?

Comment: Is you neo4j server up and running?

Comment: I never realized to check that:(,anyway thanks a lot.My connection is working fine now after starting the server.:)

Comment: The PHAR file is deprecated and very out of date. I would suggest installing the library with Composer in the future.